# Geometric Brownian Motoin versus Square root proces

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Lets say random variable S(t) is changing according to a Geometric Brownian motion
$$dS(t)=aS(t)dt+bS(t)dW(t)$$
where $W(t)$ is a standard wiener process. It is widely known that $S(T)-S(0)$ is distributed log normally with mean $(a-\frac{b^2}{2})T$ and variance $b^2T$. I would like to know if any such result exist in the case $S(t)$ is changing according to a "square root process".
$$dS(t)=aS(t)dt+b\sqrt{S(t)}dW(t)$$. 
My attempt: Let $G=log(S)$. Applying ito's lemma one can see that
$$dlogS(t)=(a-\frac{b^2}{2S})dt+\frac{b}{\sqrt{S}}dW(t)$$
Here the drift term  is bigger than in the case of GBM. This tells me that possibly, the expected value of $G$ is higher in the case of square root process than GBM. But I have not been able to find any reliable resources, or go beyond this on my own.

Comment: The equation of interest

$$dS(t)=aS(t)\,dt+b\sqrt{S(t)}\,dW(t)$$

is known as the [Cox-Ingersoll-Ross model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox–Ingersoll–Ross_model) in mathematical finance.

Comment: Do the results hold for $a>0$?. I thought that the CIR model results are only valid in the case of mean reversion.

Comment: Try multiplying both sides of the square root process by $e^{-at}$, gather terms to write $d(e^{-at}S(t)$ on the left-hand side, and then integrate to arrive at a stochastic integral equation (SIE).  You should be able to determine the mean and variance of $S(t)$ from that SIE.